# Facebook: Get picture post to feed with PHP SDK v5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I need to get pictures that are post to a page via PHP, currently it's pulling only the message but not the picture. I'm new to v5 so the questions is, how to get the picture from posts? (they are public posts on a fan page).

```
Array
(
    [message] => #cpchickenbreast  
    [created_time] => 2015-09-01T07:14:48+0000
    [id] => 148902108457774_819236841508190
)
```

Code

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
  'app_secret' => FACEBOOK_SECRET,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
  ]);

$accessToken = FACEBOOK_APP_ID.'|'.FACEBOOK_SECRET;

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);

$pagefeed = $fb->get("/" . $pageid . "/tagged?limit=3");


foreach($pagefeed->getDecodedBody() as $posts) {
    foreach($posts as $post) {
        print_r($post);
    }
}
```

With v3 I could get the feed and just access "type" data to know that it's a picture and can get picture link with the "picture" data

```
   [id] => 148902108457774_1133014613379847
    [from] => Array
    (
        [name] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        [category] => Food/Beverages
        [category_list] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2252
                        [name] => Food/Beverages
                    )

            )

        [id] => 148902108457774
    )

[message] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[story] => xxxxx
[story_tags] => Array
    (


    )

[picture] => https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfp1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/11885212_1899706113588729_9156711625894648877_n.png?oh=c98d05c819ce00da8515f04eb7cf9227&oe=5660CFC3
[link] => https://www.facebook.com/cpbalance/photos/a.1841153286110679.1073741828.1794977444061597/1899706113588729/?type=1
[name] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx .... and a lot more
```

Comment: You need to specifically ask for the fields you want now; see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, “declarative fields”

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

```
$session_token = Session::get('facebook_access_token');

        $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
            'app_id' => '{app-id}',
            'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
        ]);

        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($session_token);

        $responseTagged = $fb->get('/me?fields=tagged.limit(10){id,message}');

        $taggedNode = $responseTagged->getGraphNode();

        $taggeds = $taggedNode['tagged'];

        foreach ($taggeds as $tagged) {

            print_r($tagged['message']);
            print_r('<br>');
        }
```